# Triggering an alarm at exactly the defined time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to create an alarm for which it guarantees to be triggered at a provided time? Chrome does provide the `chrome.alarms` API which can be used to create alarms, however the system may delay the alarm indefinitely:

```
chrome.alarms.create({
    when: startTime,
    periodInMinutes: 60    // is not actually triggered every hour
});
```

The same thing goes with `setTimeout`:

```
function update(){
    console.log(new Date());
    setTimeout(update, 1 * 60 * 1000);    // also isn't triggered every minute
}
```

Just after 10 minutes of the computer being idle, the `update` loop starts being delayed.

I'm looking for a way to guarantee an alarm going off at a defined time (given the computer is on and the extension is loaded, of course).

Comment: How accurate do you need to be?

Comment: @JonSG As accurate as it can be. If I set an alarm to be triggered at 10:00 am, then it shouldn't be delayed to 11:00 am. Currently the `chrome.alarms` API will delay it for a very long duration if the computer is idle for a while.

Comment: What I am wondering is if you use the alarm API with a period of 1 (minute) and then in the callback check for *close enough (or after) your target time* if that would work for you.

Comment: The problem is that the API only takes the provided value as merely a suggestion: It won't trigger the alarm before the time you asked, but we also might delayed it for any arbitrary amount of time.

Comment: One solution I have in mind is to prevent the system entering the idle state through the `chrome.power` API. Though it's not a perfect solution, but it guarantees that the alarm will be more accurate I believe.

Comment: I was just looking at that as well :-)

Comment: Since page js is single-threaded, I guess it's really hard to guarantee the function to be triggered at specific time. There are always unexpected things (user interaction, ...) kept in the queue.

Comment: @HaibaraAi Well yes, but that is not the point. The main issue here is that Chrome will not trigger the listener/callback when the system is idle, ie the invocation of the `chrome.alarms` listener will be delayed/ the `setTimeout` update loop will stop completely until the system is active again.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, what about using `chrome.idle.onStateChanged` to detect the state change and prolong the duration?

Comment: @HaibaraAi Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't really help. Anyway, currently I'm forcing the system active as long as there's at least one alarm, and it is working perfectly fine.